# Can gravity act through time?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time, causality

I know, that gravity acts through time and space, as it propagates at the speed of light, through space.
I mean to discuss whether gravity has an effect in spacetime, along the time axis. Effects of gravity, that modify motion, are well known. The gravitational effect of "frame drag", for instance, as I understand it. effects the space furureward of the worldline of its source. (The space behind a moving object, in changing 3 dimensional space.)
I'm asking: does gravity from event A, at an earlier time t1 affect event B, later at the same x,y,z, space location at time t2?

I know this question is  'odd'...
{And probably pointless. because I see no way to breach the subject of what effects gravity might have, along the time axis. (there is no established expectation, and Very scarce 'anomalous data.)}
...
In spacetime, two events may happen at one location in space, at different times.
event A, at x,y,z,t1. And event B, at x,y,z,t2.
If a gravitational body is at event A, can its gravity affect the area of event B?

I avoid thinking about any effect of gravity from event B on A because that would be 'spooky' (faster than light propagation).
I understand, that for A and B to be at the same x,y,z location in spacetime, they must both be in motion. Say, for this example, with the same velocity V.
I am thinking as an example, of an event A, being the center of gravity, of a spherical gravitational body Ab, with mass M and Radius R, crossing the space-point x,y,z, at time t1, and an event B, being the crossing of the following surface of Ab, at x,y,z, at time t2, in their joint motion. t2-t1 = R/V.

The distance in spacetime is the spacetime interval. In this simple case, it is only their distance in time R/V, times C, speed of light: $CR/V$.
{The effect of gravity along the time axis would be very slight as the 'spacetime interval' distance along the time axis is $3*10^8$ meters/second
A significant effect, should only be seen in cases where mass and velocity are large.

Comment: A gravitational body, as much as any other body, is not an event.

Comment: See edit in 'op'.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic effects propagate in free space at the speed of light, so an object at point A sees the electromagnetic field from another object at point B only after the time interval that a light wave takes to travel from B to A.  The same is true of gravity,  because gravitational effects also propagate at the speed of light.

Comment: In this case A and B are at the same location in space. zero distance/c = 'has time to get to the future'.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which travels along the time axis in certain frame is at rest at that frame. As light speed is invariant, there is no way to make anything traveling at the speed of light at rest in certain frame and therefore it cannot travel along time axis.

From what I know, the speed of propagation of gravity always refers to speed of propagation of gravitational waves. These waves travel at light speed so wave sent from event A cannot effect the event B in your question, unless spacetime is curved in such a way, that the wave returns back.

Comment: A body at rest, moves in a sense along the time axis, at the rate of one second per second. That is moving a spacetime interval of $3*10^8$ meters. 
I mean, it 'persists' to the future. It gets there. In time.

Comment: Something traveling at the speed of light, may travel zero distance, Instantaneously. Yes? 
I mean, it may, '. It may get there. In time.

Comment: I mean perhaps gravity propagates directly along the time axis. 'iAs well as in space, at C.

Comment: @BruceAW the speed of light $c=3*10^8ms^{-1}$ is given by **spatial** distance divided by time. If spatial distance is zero, the speed is zero. If you wish to talk about 4D view, where being at rest is seen as traveling along the time axis, then in this 4D view speed of light is always 0, not c. So if spacetime interval is any nonzero number, the thing traveling at light speed cannot travel there.

Comment: The spacetime interval.(say "s". $s^2 = d^2 + (ct)^2. s, spacetime interval. d, space distance. the traditional form is s^2 = d^ - (ct^2. But for some reason the time is in imaginary numbers, so the square is negative and they subtract it.

Comment: The spacetime interval.(say "s". $s^2 = d^2 + (ct)^2. s, spacetime interval. d, space distance. the traditional form is s^2 = d^ - (ct^2. But for some reason the time is in imaginary numbers, so the square is negative and they subtract it. But if light tavels 3*10^8 meters, in one second the spacetime interval is sqrt[2*(3*10^8)^2. that is

Comment: I see light travels a diagonal thru spacetime. Not just up time. Point taken.